# Regular expression to match numbers with a slight issue

Tags: regex, numbers

My problem is to extract numbers from a list of currency list.

My test data would be something like this

```
$100.00
AUD 2012.00
Rs. 234.0 ASD
133 USD
Another thing 1233S.E122
Blah Blah 1.23 
SG$ 013.3
23.03 Something
Something T1233S.122S Else
Whatever 2
```

And the regular expression I came up with is

```
(\d+)\.?(\d+)?
```

So basically, a number followed by an optional dot and another optional number.

So [while this works fine](http://bit.ly/pK7REQ), it works a little way more than I want. For an example it matches

the 1233 and 122 in `1233S.E122` and same for `T1233S.122S`

I understand that because I run it with the **global flag**, all the digits are matched.

How would I make it NOT match those that contains a non-digit in the start, middle or end ?

Please be kind enough to give brief explanation for your answer as I am a beginner in RegEx .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some word boundaries...

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

This will match numbers with an optional decimal place that are surrounded by word boundaries.

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?2uvcc).

I also *tidied up* your regex a bit, assuming you want to match the whole number and not the decimal individually.

Comment: Works great :) What does the `?:` do? I came up with `\b(\d+)\.?(\d+)?\b` and looks like it's working fine. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray: `?:` just makes a capturing group non capturing.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a maximum of one non-digit character and you know that character is always capital, you should be able to define a character range like [A-Z]*.  The star tells the script to look for 0 or 1 character in that range, and without anything before it, that character can be anywhere in the sequence.

If you want to only look for non-numeric characters at the very beginning of the string, put a "^" symbol before the range like this: "^[A-Z]".  This will only look for an upper-case letter at the beginning of the string; you would have to specifically restrict the range everywhere else if you don't want letters showing up elsewhere.

You can also REQUIRE numbers like this: "[0-9]+".  This would match one or more characters in that range, which ensures you get SOMETHING with a number.

In all, it would look something like this (assuming that a letter can be anywhere):

/[A-Z]*[0-9]+./g (for javascript)

Hope that helps.